# Time shifting in time series forecasting

Tags: time-series, forecasting, artificial-intelligence

I am working on an ANN model for univariate time series forecasting. The step size is 1, so I try to forecast value of t+1, using value of t. Unfortunately, my forecasts have time shift problem. The obtained forecasts for t+1 is more fit to the value of t as shown in figure. 
How can I avoid this problem? Can I shift one step back the forecasts and is there a paper about this issue? [image]

Comment: It looks like your network is just mimicking a random walk (i.e. the best forecast for t+1 is the value at t). Try doing a multi-step forecast instead of a one step ahead forecast.

Comment: Thanks @SkanderH. I tried multi-step forecasting, but how can I determine the step size? Can you suggest a way? Should I make a correlation analysis to determine the step size (lag)?